# Thrift causing undefined method 'write_struct_begin' on all IO objects

Tags: ruby, thrift

I'm running into a strange error... After I call a thrift method, all file IO I try to do fails with errors like:

```
log writing failed. undefined method `write_struct_begin'
```

This occurs if I try to do logger.info etc., or even if I just open a file directly, and try to write to it.

Totally stumped!

Comment: I'm not sure (no Ruby experience) but could this one be related? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2184 - Could be a good idea to ask that question on the mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Thrift interface I was consuming defined a type called "File". As soon as I pulled in the generated Ruby code for this file it rewrote the built-in File class. It would be nice if ruby's thrift generator namespaced things better!